# How to add data in data-content tag of popover at run time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Boostrap in MVC application.

I am trying to add the data to display in popover run time.
but its not working...

I have this code...

```
<html>
<body>
   <a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-danger" rel="popover" data-content="" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover">hover for popover</a>  
</body>
</html>



 <script>


        $(function () {
            $("#example").popover("Adding data run time here...");
        });



    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.attr()` function](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-value):

```
$("#example").attr("data-content", "Adding data run time here...");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer...

```
<html>
<body>
   <a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-danger" rel="popover" data-content="" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover">hover for popover</a>  
</body>
</html>

<script>

    $(function () {
        $("#example").attr("data-content", getData()).popover();
    });

    function getData()
    {
        return "Here is the runtime data";
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

hover for popover

$("#example").popover({
                placement: 'top',
                content: 'Add data here',
            });